# Salto de linea en excel

Tags: excel

tengo un problema con una formula en Excel, estoy intentando copiar un texto desde un hoja de calculo a otra. Tengo el código que lo copia pero al copiar ignora los saltos de linea, alguien sabe como podria arreglar esto? muchas gracias.
[image: texto a copiar]
[image: Texto copiado]

Comment: Edita la pregunta y muestra el código

Comment: Tal vez solo es problema de formato en la celda destino

Comment: que el cheese gratin sea parmesano sino no vale

Answer (score 0):

No sé cual es tu código pero en tu fórmula lo único que haces es llamar al valor de la celda `A1` en la hoja `main1`. Por eso, lo único que tienes es el texto, sin su formato. Tal y como @tecnologer ha dicho en su comentario, es cuestión del formato de la celda de destino.

Tienes 2 opciones:

1. Ajustar texto
2. Copiar el formato de la celda origen.

Es lo único que tienes que hacer. Prueba y nos cuentas.

Answer (score -1):

Luego de traer el contenido de la celda origen, ajusta el texto de la celda destino.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]